# Desktop icons disappeared

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, icons

My desktop icons are gone, how can I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

**Desktop->View->Show Desktop icons** must solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tried right clicking the Desktop > View > Show desktop icons?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running XP, right click the Desktop > Arrange Icons By > Show Desktop Icons.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've checked that right clicking and "Arrange Icons By > Show Desktop Icons" is ticked the only other thing that springs to mind is that the Desktop Cleanup Wizard has run and removed your unused icons, which could well be most/all of them if you use the menus, Quick Launch or something like Launchy to run your programs.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious solutions listed above, on a desktop I've noticed that when I unplug my computer from the wall and then reboot, my desktop icons are all showing and rearranged, this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Tuneup utilities (demo or full) to solve the problem. It can be due to registry problem or **the icons can be moved**